# Total ion current normalisation of intensities derived from mass spec - does this produce compositional data?

Tags: mass-spectrometry

A definition of total ion current normalisation from https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=86606, i.e. for each feature in the sample, divide its intensity value by the total for the sample.

If I have my features in columns and samples in rows, and for each sample/row I divide the intensity of each feature by the sum of all intensities for that sample (e.g. R code would be ...

```
  TIC <- apply(data, 1, function(i){
   out <- i/sum(i)
  }
    )
```

When I then check the sum of the values for each sample, this equates to one, much like the calculation of relative abundance from OTU data, where the relative abundance sums to 1 or 100% for each sample. Is the calculation of TIC in this format correct and does this now result in compositional data? Most of the R packages that would have automated the calculation of the TIC are no longer available, so any input on calculation would be appreciated. Thank you